# R - adding legend to ggmap (ggplot2) while using annotate

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend, ggmap

FYI: I'm fairly new to ggplot2 and ggmap so I apologize for the sloppy code but it is the only way I've been able to plot sets of groups of points where each group has it's own color. Also my os is ubuntu.

I'm trying to add a legend, to a ggmap object and in particular a legend with a continuos gradient transitioning the colors.  Any advice?  I've tried the legend attribute in ggmap but it doesn't seem to be working. Below is what I have so far.

```
syd = get_map(location = center, zoom = zoom, maptype = type,color = "bw")

(SYDmap = ggmap(syd, extent = "panel",legend="right")+ annotate('point',x=lng[[1]],xend=max(lng[[1]]),y=lat[[1]],yend=max(lat[[1]]),colour=colorval[1],cex=cexval,pch=pchval))

for(i in 2:(topnum - 1))
  SYDmap<- SYDmap + annotate('point',x=lng[[i]],xend=max(lng[[i]]),y=lat[[i]],yend=max(lat[[i]]),colour=colorval[i],cex=cexval,pch=pchval)

i=topnum;  (SYDmap <-   SYDmap + annotate('point',x=lng[[i]],xend=max(lng[[i]]),y=lat[[i]],yend=max(lat[[i]]),colour=colorval[i],cex=cexval,pch=pchval)) + guides(fill = "colourbar")
```

Comment: I don't think you meant to post two identical questions. This one has better tags, so I'm going to start the process of deleting the previous one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R - adding legend to ggmap (ggplot2) while using annotate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918057/r-adding-legend-to-ggmap-ggplot2-while-using-annotate)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `annotate`, here's a method that adds a point layer using `geom_point`. Almost any geom can be added to a ggmap object as it would be added to a ggplot object. Because `Size` (see the contents of the `df` data frame below) is a colour aesthetic in the call to `geom_point`, the legend is generated automatically.

```
library(ggmap)

# Get a map - A map of Canberra will do
ACTmap = get_map(c(149.1, -35.325), zoom = 12, source = "google", maptype = "roadmap")

# A data frame of lon and lat coordinates and the variable Size
df = data.frame(lon = c(149.0307, 149.1326, 149.089, 149.048, 149.0965),
            lat = c(-35.3892, -35.28225, -35.34005, -35.34857, -35.34833),
            Size = c(1,2,3,4,5))

# Draw the map
ACTmap = ggmap(ACTmap)

# Add the points
ACTmap = ACTmap + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour = Size), 
      alpha = 0.6,  size = 10)

# Change the legend
ACTmap + scale_colour_continuous(low = "red", high = "blue", space = "Lab", guide = "colorbar")
```

[image]