# Add a legend to the ggmap

Tags: r, legend, ggmap

I am trying to add a legend to a `ggmap` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918102/r-adding-legend-to-ggmap-ggplot2-while-using-annotate?rq=1). It looks very good. But the first problem is, that `scale_colour_continuous` is only for two colour, but I need to use three colours. Secondly, event when I tried to use only two colors (which looked very bad), I failed. My code looks like:

```
 ee<-runif(100,min=-6, max=26)
 nn<-runif(100, min=30, max=75)
 r<-colorRampPalette(colors=c("white", "red2", "black"))
 aa<-round(runif(100, min=1, max=35),0)
 barv<-r(10)[as.numeric(cut(aa, breaks=10))]
 z<-data.frame(ee, nn,barv)
 my_map<-get_map(location='Europe', zoom = 3, maptype='satellite')
 p2<-ggmap(my_map)+
 theme(text=element_text(size=15))
 p2<-p2+geom_point(data=z, aes(x=ee, y=nn), colour=barv, 
 alpha = 0.5, size=2.5)
 p2
 #p2 + scale_color_continuous(low="white", high="black", 
 #space = "Lab", guide = "colorbar")
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `scale_color_gradient2` for that. You can define a `low`, a `mid` and a `high` color value and also determine where the `midpoint` has to be on the scale:

```
# adding 'aa' as a column to your dataframe
z <- data.frame(ee, nn, barv, aa)

# create the plot
ggmap(my_map)+
  geom_point(data=z, aes(x=ee, y=nn, colour=aa), alpha = 0.5, size=2.5) +
  scale_color_gradient2(low="green", mid="red",high="blue", midpoint=18,
                        breaks=c(10,20,30), labels=c("ten","twenty","thirty")) +
  theme(text=element_text(size=15))
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Wonderfull! Last thing, can I replace numbers in the legend by text? Thx a lot!